# How do you disable indent checking on esLint?

Tags: eslint

The indent rule seems impossible to disable; how (in config settings) do I disable this rule? thanks.

Answer (score 88):

Set the rule to `"off"` in your config like this:

```
"rules": {
  "indent": "off"
}
```

You can read more in [the docs here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules).

Comment: `"indent": 0` obviously works, but for the sake of readability and consistency with the official docs, the recommended way to write that is `"indent": "off"`.

Comment: http://shripalsoni.com/blog/configure-eslint-in-visual-studio-code/

put this in ```.eslintrc```

Comment: for me work fine: ```"indent-legacy": "off"```

Answer (score 27):

For indentation, I usually let it activated in config and disable it only in some files where I need a fancy indentation, hence I use the comment

```
/* eslint-disable indent */
```

It is worth to note that this works also with [standardJS](https://standardjs.com/) as well as on any other linter powered by eslint.

Answer (score 17):

I had to add more rules. To turn off linting for `react` and `jsx-indent`

```
"rules": {
    "indent": "off",
    "react/jsx-indent": "off",
    "react/jsx-indent-props": "off"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the one that worked for me

```
"indent": ["error", ""],
```

Answer (score 1):

In my webstorm project I had to put the following in my `.eslintrc.js` (I think this would work the same for `.eslintrc` or `.eslintrc.json`):

```
rules: {
    // other rule,
    // other rule,
    '@typescript-eslint/indent': 'off',    <---- add this rule
    // other rule
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For typescript, we can utilize the following on the individual file at the top of the page which will disable eslint check for indent

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/indent */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you disable indent checking, remember to restart local server to get rid off the errors.